# Conversion problems with NuSOAP and Delphi XE2

Tags: php, delphi, character-encoding, delphi-xe2, nusoap

My team and I have a problem with the codification of the strings that we are using in our delphi software:

The string follows the next process:

Delphi String->SOAPMessage->Internet->NuSoap->SQLServer

The collation of the SQLServer is Modern_Spanish_CI_AS because we are Spaniards. The SOAPMessage has the ISO-8856-1 encoding.

So the fun starts with the "specials characters" as ñ,í,ó,etc...

When we introduce one of these characters in the DB " Ñ " becomes in " Ã‘ " for instance.

We guess that the problem is in the nuSoap parser and PHP because before the message processing in the server we introduce the raw data in a SQL server table and the characters are readable.

All the posts that I read so far related with codification in NuSoap become from people who want to use the Utf-8. But the problem is that we want to use ISO-8856-1 encoding. Any idea to introduce this special characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The patch that we applied it's awful but it's working now, so the http header now has ISO-8856-1 Encoding, and the content of the xml also has ISO-8856-1 encoding, but we needed to modify the xml header to show literally Utf-8. At the end, the message had this format:

```
<Http header>
    charset="ISO-8856-1"
</Http Header>

<content>

    <xml encoding ="UTF-8">
        Body encoded using ISO-8856-1 
    </xml>
</content>
```

The problem is in the nusoap parser and we are moving to another library. Meanwhile that worked.